# One Instance of useState() Overriding the Other in React App

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I have a functional component in my React/Ionic app, in which I need to keep track of state for two things: 1.) the final selections a user makes from a multiple choice series of questions. And 2.) when the user has made a selection for each of the questions, at which point I conditionally show my "Submit Answers" button based on the boolean state of a `questionsAnswered` property - handled with my `useState()`.

The problem I'm running into is that, even though these are defined as two separate instances of `useState()`, one overrides the other. Specifically, when a user has selected an option for each question, my submit button shows as expected, but when the score generated based on those selections is passed to the next component, it is passed as 0 - suggesting `useState()` has reset everything back to the default state.

To be clear, when I don't set the state for the three questions having answers - in other words if I just leave the "Submit Answers" button visible, and don't hide it using a conditional handled in my first `useState()` instance, then the correct `score`, handled in my second instance of `useState()`, gets forwarded.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here. Also, if there's a different way to handle conditionally handling showing my "Submit Answers" button I'm open to hearing it. But either way, I'm not sure how to use two instances of `useState()` like this, without them interfering with each other.

Here is my component in full, using some mock data:

```
import {
  IonButtons,
  IonContent,
  IonHeader,
  IonMenuButton,
  IonPage,
  IonTitle,
  IonToolbar,
  IonRadioGroup,
  IonList,
  IonLabel,
  IonListHeader,
  IonItem,
  IonRadio,
  IonItemDivider,
  IonButton,
  IonCard,
  IonCardContent,
} from "@ionic/react";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useHistory } from "react-router";
import { APIConfig } from "./../../../environments/environment";

const Questions: React.FC = () => {
  let [questionsAnswered, setAnswered] = useState(false);
  let [locQuestions, setAnswers] = useState<locQuestions[]>([]);

  let score = 0;
  const history = useHistory();

  let questions = [
    {
      id: 1,
      question: "What is the closest planet to the sun?",
      choices: ["Mercury", "Mars", "Venus", "Earth"],
      answer: "Mercury",
      choice: "",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      question: "What is known as 'the Red Planet'?",
      choices: ["Jupiter", "Mars", "Venus", "Saturn"],
      answer: "Mars",
      choice: "",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      question: "What planet has the 'Giant Red Spot'?",
      choices: ["Neptune", "Venus", "Jupiter", "Mars"],
      answer: "Jupiter",
      choice: "",
    },
  ];

  const getChoice = (qId: any, qChoice: any) => {
    locQuestions = [...questions];
    for (let loc of locQuestions) {
      if (loc.id === qId) {
        loc.choice = qChoice;
      }
    }
    checkIfAnswersComplete();
  };

  const checkIfAnswersComplete = () => {
    let answeredArr = locQuestions.filter((i) => i.choice !== "");
    if (answeredArr.length === locQuestions.length) {
      console.log("All questions answered!!!");
      setAnswered(true); // Set to true here, because all questions are answered
    }
  };

  const getScore = () => {
    setAnswers(locQuestions); // State for the final choices made by user
    for (const q of locQuestions) {
      console.log("locQuestions in getScore(): ", q);
      if (q.answer === q.choice) {
        score++;
      }
    }
    return score;
  };

  const submitAnswers = async () => {
    getScore();
    await updateUser();
    history.push("/score", score); // When score gets sent it's now 0
  };

  const updateUser = async (
    username = "tester",
    lastCompletedSet = "1",
    lastCompletedTopic = "starter",
    pointsToAdd = score
  ) => {
    let result: object;
    const req = `users/update-user-stats`;
    const body = {
      username,
      lastCompletedSet,
      lastCompletedTopic,
      pointsToAdd,
    };
    result = await axios.post(`${APIConfig.url}/${req}`, body);
  };

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonButtons slot="start">
            <IonMenuButton />
          </IonButtons>
          <IonTitle>Questions</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent>
        <IonCard>
          <IonCardContent>
            <IonList>
              {questions.map((q, questionIndex) => (
                <IonRadioGroup key={q.id}>
                  <IonListHeader>
                    <IonLabel class="question">{q?.question}</IonLabel>
                  </IonListHeader>
                  {q.choices.map((choice, optionIndex) => (
                    <IonItem key={choice[optionIndex]}>
                      <IonLabel>{choice}</IonLabel>
                      <IonRadio
                        slot="start"
                        value={choice}
                        onClick={() => getChoice(q.id, choice)}
                      ></IonRadio>
                    </IonItem>
                  ))}
                </IonRadioGroup>
              ))}
            </IonList>
            <IonItemDivider className="divider"></IonItemDivider>
            {questionsAnswered ? (
              <IonButton expand="block" onClick={() => submitAnswers()}>
                SUBMIT ANSWERS
              </IonButton>
            ) : null}
          </IonCardContent>
        </IonCard>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Questions;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
locQuestions = [...questions];
```

You are mutating the state directly. You should never do that. Instead you should update `locQuestion` by calling `setLocQuestions` with a new array.

I've created a codesandbox that shows how this can work.

Posted here as well:

```
  const [locQuestions, setQuestions] = useState(questions);
  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState([]);

  const areAllQuestionsAnswered =
    answers.filter(Boolean).length === locQuestions.length;

  const getChoice = (qId, qChoice) => {
    setAnswers((currentAnswers) => {
      const result = [...currentAnswers];
      result[qId] = qChoice;
      return result;
    });
  };

  const getScore = () => {
    let score = 0;
    locQuestions.forEach((q) => {
      if (q.answer === answers[q.id]) {
        score++;
      }
    });
    return score;
  };

  const submitAnswers = async () => {
    getScore();
    console.log("score is:", getScore());
    // await updateUser();
  };
```

[image: Edit beautiful-drake-t7vzq]

Comment: 1.) I'm using the spread operator here, to explicitly not mutate the state of the `questions` array. 2.) Are you suggesting this is key to my issue here? If so please clarify how so, because it's not clear to me.

Comment: It's the assignment that mutates state, not whether you spread the values or not. `locQuestions = anything` is mutating state. This is why  **state variables should always be consts**. It helps you keep state immutable.

Comment: It's not clear to me how to implement this, then. I'm not clear on where/how I make a copy of my `questions` array. Some code to demonstrate would be helpful.

Comment: I get score is `0` on your implementation, after selecting 3 correct answers?

Comment: The `forEach` logic is just slightly off. It should be `answers[q.id]` instead of `answers[qIdx]`. The answers were set by ID so they need to be retrieved by ID as well, not the index.

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I've fixed the code as @BrianThompson noted

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your state, you have to use the `set` function returned from React's `useState`. The reason is that React needs to know when to rerender, and if you assign a value to the state variable directly it will not trigger a rerender, hence not updating the value on screen and to child components.

TL;DR:

```
locQuestions = [...questions];
```

into

```
setAnswers([...questions])
```

Comment: I tried making that one change to the line you highlighted. But it still sent `0` as the final `score`, when it should have been `3`, after 3 correct answers had been selected.